# Change the classifier decision by using the probability estimates

Tags: classification, stochastic-processes, model

I have a stream of documents composed of $1$ to $n$ pages. The objective is to segment the stream of documents. Every first and last page of a document is classified as either the beginning $b$ or ending $e$ of the document. The probability of belonging to either classes is also computed. 
[image: stream of documents]

I want to study the relation between documents to decide if they can be fused together or to confirm the segmentation. For that I have $4$ cases. My question concerns the $3rd$ and $4th$ cases.

1. Case 1: If the last page of the first document is classified as $e$ and the first page of the successive document is classified as $b$. $(e,b)$ Then I consider that the first document is correct and I move on to the last page of the successive document etc.
2. Case 2: If both pages are classified as $(e,e)$ then I fuse the documents
3. **Case 3:** In the case of $(b,b)$ I want to change it to $(b,e)$
4. **Case 4:** In the case of $(b,e)$ I want to change it to $(e,b)$

Can I change the decision of the classifier? Can I compute the cost (`Loss function`) for switching for example from $(b,b) \longrightarrow (b,e)$ taking into account that I have the probability estimates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this should be possible. Although you're not dealing with an active learning problem, it does remind me of [one approach in that domain](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.5409&rep=rep1&type=pdf). One technique people use to identify samples that need expert annotation, in support vector machine-driven active learning, is data points are identified that, if their predicted class were to change, it would most greatly affect the position of the decision boundary. You may be able to approach quantifying the change in decision cost using a technique like this. Are you using SVMs for your classifier? If so, this might be a good approach. If not, you may be able to go about it by avoiding over-ridding the classifier decision on those cases that would lead to more frequent misclassifications in your already-labeled data.

Comment: hey @Kyle. I am actually using an SVM as a classifier yes. It's the first time that I have to deal with this problem. The article sounds like a good start for me. I'll let you know If i have questions

Comment: @Hani Gotc: Sounds good! I've built systems doing this sort of thing before. It shouldn't be too hard to code, if you're already working in a classification software pipeline of some kind!